# Is there documentation for rotating AWS RDS certificates?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

AWS keeps sending me prompts to modify my database to update the certificates. Is there any documentation on how to do this that isn't the infinite loop of Amazon's?

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the complete procedure using the console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL-certificate-rotation.html).

Anyway, an important point is that **if your client apps don't use SSL at all to connect to the RDS databases, then you don't need to care about RDS certificates update**. Otherwise you will need to add the new certificate to the client trust store prior to updating the certificate.

For example, we had around 30 databases that needed an update, but none of them used SSL on the database side so it was trivial.

Last but not least, the current AWS certificate will expire tomorrow (5th of March 2020).

Answer (score 0):

That's all you need to know about that problem: https://aws.amazon.com/ru/blogs/database/amazon-rds-customers-update-your-ssl-tls-certificates-by-february-5-2020/